# remix nested routes in folder can't be find

Tags: reactjs, typescript, remix

EveryBody
I use the remix to build a simple page which want to use folders to orgnize the routes.
This is my project directory

```
- app/
  - root.tsx
  - examples/
    - route.tsx
    - child1/
      - account.tsx
```

In `examples` directory, it has a `route.tsx`, content is

```
import { Outlet } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function Examples() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>ExampleRoute</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the child1 export the react ui components named `Account`

```
export default function Account() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Accout</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

But When I open `/examples/child1`, the server return 404.
What mistakes did I make ?

I read the remix doc about the nested folders, but there is only one level nests.
And I ask the gpt, it tell me the exampels should have route.tsx, so the remix can recognize it as route

Answer (score 3):

Only the folders directly beneath app/routes will be registered as a route. Deeply nested folders are ignored. The file at app/routes/about/header/route.tsx will not create a route.[1](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/discussion/routes#what-is-nested-routing)